# Implement one-to-many, parent-child relationship between two or more models in Entity Framework CF 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Suppose I have a model like the following:

```
public class A{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

And I have another model like the following:

```
public class B{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public int AId { get; set;}
    public string Type { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public int SlNo { get; set;}
}
```

Basically, I want to have a **One-to-many, Parent-Child** relationship between `A` and `B`, so that `AId` will act like a foreign key to `A`, and the same value of `AId` may be present in multiple instances of `B`.

How to achieve this in Entity Framework CF 5, ASP.NET MVC 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of class B, just add a navigation property to class A.  Then the code-first conventions will be able to infer the relationship.  This ought to do it:

```
public class A{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs {get; set;}
}

public class B{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public int AId { get; set;}
    public string Type { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public int SlNo { get; set;}

    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What if there is a **One-to-many** type of parent-child relationship between models `A` and `B`? I mean one single id of `A` can be present in multiple instances of `B`.

Comment: Sir my question is updated now. I want to implement **One-to-many, parent-child** relationship in EF CF 5.

Comment: Yes, the example I gave above should create a One-To-Many relationship.  One A ==> Many Bs.  I've made an additional change to make this more clear ... I added a navigation property into the "A" class.